# How to get linq to transform data from one form to another

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have objects:

```
public class PaymentHeader
{
   public Payee Payee { get; set; }
   public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
   public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Payee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So a PaymentHeader has a Payee and a list of Payments.

What I was wanting was to transform this data into a slightly different format.

So I was after a `List<Payee>` where each Payee has a `List<PaymentHeader>`

I started by going:

```
var data = paymentHeaders.GroupBy(x => x.Payee)
```

So here I was trying to achieve getting all the Payees with their associated PaymentHeaders. I think this is the right starting point but I don't know how to get any further. I think I need to create an anonymous type but am unsure how to put the Payees into a list and add the list of PaymentHeaders for each Payee.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to build a type to hold this, or use an anonymous type:

```
var data = paymentHeaders.GroupBy(x => x.Payee)
               .Select(g => new { Payee = g.Key, Headers = g.ToList() })
               .ToList();

foreach(var d in data)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Payee {0} has {1} headers", d.Payee, d.Headers.Count);
}
```